# How to use laravel migrations

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am using Laravel framework of php for development. I want to use migration for table creation-manipulation. These are the steps I took:

1. I create migration with command `php artisan migrate:make create_users_table`, which create a migration file and in its up function, I wrote down my schema and then I ran it and it got successfully executed.
2. After that, I tried again run the same migration and as a result, its shows the error that, 'table exist'.
3. Then I tried to use rollback function but it give error 'nothing to roll back' .

   So, how to rollback that migration or to execute down function of migration. Also, when I created new migration and in migration file's up function, I wrote code for dropping table created by my earlier migration and I execute with command `php artisan migrate` , by this all migration got executed (also my earlier one) and shows me the error, 'table already exist' (obvious).

So, now I'm stuck, is there a function to execute a special/particular migration? How do I do this?

Comment: run 'composer dump-autoload' then try again, artisan migrate:reset if rollback is not working (it will rollback all migrations)

Comment: do i need to create a migration file each time and write in its up function for every change or creating new table or column and is it necessary to use migration and why they are even used ?

Comment: Migrations are soooo useful, they are version control for your database like git/svn for your code. You create new file if you want to change something, unless you have single migration file and wish to simply rewrite it. Do as Jason told you and put both UP and DOWN in one migration file

Answer (score 2):

When you create a migration with `artisan migrate:make` you should write the `up` and `down` methods. The `down` method should do the OPPOSITE of what the `up` method does.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    // We DROP the table because we created it in the "up" method.
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

It sounds to me like you have some code in your `up` method that doesn't belong there, although this is hard to say without seeing your code. I suggest you clear our the `migrations` table (there may or may not be any records). You'll also need to manually drop the table you created through the migration. Then you can start fresh.

Remember you can also use `dropIfExists` to drop a table only if it exists.

```
public function down()
{
    // Drop the table only if it exists.
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Comment: i want to run down function of a particular migration ,how to do that.after that particular migration ,i ran another few migrations that i want to keep,so how to run drop function

Answer (score 0):

when you create 1 migration in laravel, each of migration include 2 method: 'up()' and 'down()'.

+) up() method will be excuted when you run command 'php artisan migrate'.

+) down() method will be excuted when you quan to come back the status before you run command "php artisan migrate".

you can try excuting command: 'php artisan migrate:refresh' to rollback all of migration and after excute command 'php artisan migrate' auto.